# how to prevent print enter key (\n) being print in output area

Tags: c, printf, fgets

I have a problem with the print output, every time it prints "12" it enters down and I don't know what is the problem, i have tried print it separately but no luck (code below)

the question

A baseball player’s batting average is calculated as the number of hits divided
by the official number of at-bats. In calculating official at-bats, walks, sacrifices,
and occasions when hit by the pitch are not counted. Write a program
that takes an input file containing player numbers and batting records. Trips to
the plate are coded in the batting record as follows: H—hit, O—out, W—walk,
S—sacrifice, and P—hit by pitch. The program should output for each player
the input data followed by the batting average. (Hint: Each batting record is
followed by a newline character.)

Sample input file:

12 HOOOWSHHOOHPWWHO

4 OSOHHHWWOHOHOOO

7 WPOHOOHWOHHOWOO

Corresponding output:

Player 12's record: HOOOWSHHOOHPWWHO

Player 12's batting average: 0.455

Player 4's record: OSOHHHWWOHOHOOO

Player 4's batting average: 0.417

Player 7's record: WPOHOOHWOHHOWOO

Player 7's batting average: 0.364

the code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    char str[1000];
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    char ch = 'H';
    char ch2 = 'O';
    double top = 0;
    double bottom = 0;
    double avg;
    char PN[1000];

    printf("Enter player's number:");
    fgets(PN, sizeof(PN), stdin);

    printf("Enter a record: ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) { //counts H//
        if (ch == str[i])
            ++count;
        top = count;
    }

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) { //counts O//
        if (ch2 == str[i])
            ++count2;
        bottom = count2;
    }

    avg = top / (top + bottom); // H / ( H + O ) //


    printf("Player %s's record: %s", PN, str);

    printf("Player %s's batting average: %.3lf", PN, avg);


    return 0;
}
```

my code's output

```
input
Enter player's number:12
Enter a record: HOOOWSHHOOHPWWHO

output
Player 12
's record: HOOOWSHHOOHPWWHO
Player 12
's batting average: 0.455
```

should be

```
Player 12's record: HOOOWSHHOOHPWWHO
Player 12's batting average: 0.455
```

Comment: Hint: `fgets(PN, sizeof(PN), stdin);` how much of the input does it read? (if you read from a file, that is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) reads and stores the trailing newline in the buffer. One way of getting rid of that is to use [`strcspn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn), like

```
PN[strcspn(PN, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: thankyou so much for helping me
but can you explain how ```strcspn()``` work?

Comment: Please read the linked man page, please ask if you have trouble understanding any specific part.

Answer (score 0):

**A Quick Solution**: Add just **one** line of code to yours:

```
printf("Enter player's number:");

// ------------    note that <string.h> needs to be included
PN[strlen(PN)-1]='\0';   //   <------here
// ------------

fgets(PN, sizeof(PN), stdin);
```

---

**More Information**:

For function `fgets`, according to [man7](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) 's definitions:

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array
> pointed to by s **until n-1 bytes** are read, or a  is read
> and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered.
> A null byte shall **be written immediately after the last byte read**
> into the array

After `fgets`, the data is copied to `PN` buffer from stdio stream buffer using size `sizeof(PN)` (i.e 1000), the resulting PN will be like this:

```
{ '1' , '2' , '\n' , '\0' , '\0' , '\0' , ...... }
```

After that, when you are calling `printf`, some of characters of `PN` will be copied to STDOUT (i.e. shell), and they are something like this:

```
{ '1' , '2' , '\n' , '\0' }     // note that '\0' is just an terminator, and will not be displayed on screen.
```

, which includes one more character than we need, and that character is a newline character `\n`.

When you are calling `printf("Player %s's record: %s", PN, str);`, the newline character `\n` will be treated as a *control character*, which results in an effect of `ENTER` key, this is the reason **why your program always enters down while printing "12".**

Comment: thankyou too for helping me 
is it taking the length of the string then reducing it by 1?

Comment: yes exactly, I've also added some of more specific explanations here. And while this solution works just fine, there are many other effective solutions, such as @Sourav Ghosh 's suggestions.